# Iron-Ajax displaying [Object object]

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

Currently I have a database named test and a table called users. The users table has columns id, name, and contact. Using iron-ajax I want to grab the name from the database table and display it.

just doing {{ajaxResponse}}
displayed a specific number of data existing in the database table. So if I had 6 rows in the database there will be 6 [object Objects] being printed out.

The other existing ajaxReponse were just there to test to see if it would display the values existing in the database which it didn't.

here is my iron ajax code.

```
<iron-ajax 
    auto
    url="scripts/getPost.php"
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
</iron-ajax>
<span>{{ajaxResponse}}</span>
<span>{{name}}</span>
<span>{{users}}</span>
<span>{{users.name}}</span>
<span>{{ajaxResponse.name}}</span>
<span>{{ajaxResponse.users.name}}</span>
<span>{{ajaxResponse.test.users.name}}</span>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this and display the names of the existing data in the database.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct your grammar as well as your punctuation. I can't really understand what you wrote.

Comment: What data is your Ajax call returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding what you wrote as you're making an Ajax call and an array of object are being returned, you should use a template-repeat to iterate your results:

```
<iron-ajax 
    auto
    url="scripts/getPost.php"
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
</iron-ajax>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]">
  <div>[[item.name]]</div>
</template>
```

If your results are [{name:"First name"},{name:"Second name"},{name:"Third name"},{name:"Forth name"}]
Then the above will give you a list of 4 names.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. It was missing the dom-repeat template tag that prevented to display the actual data.